# Disable GraalVM in IntellIJ JUnits

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5, graalvm

My builds and tests run fine from the CLI, but when I tried to run my Junits from IntelliJ, I was surprised to find:

> > Task :nativeCompile FAILED
>
> Execution failed for task ':nativeCompile'.
> Determining GraalVM installation failed with message: 'gu' at
> '/Users/kurtg/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.2-open/bin/gu' tool wasn't
> found. This probably means that JDK at isn't a GraalVM distribution.

This is my first immersion into the world of GraalVM.   I found this in my `build.gradle.kts` which should disable it:

> graalvmNative.toolchainDetection.set(false)

But, intelliJ isn't honoring it.     GraalVM looks cool, but at the moment, it's spam being pushed on my plate.   How do I disable it and get my JUnits running from IntelliJ?

Comment: Apparently IntelliJ tries to use regular JDK at `'/Users/kurtg/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.2-open` while it needs a GraalVM JDK. This  has nothing to do with toolchain detection (which refers to native compiler and linker)

Comment: I don't think so as the "> Task :nativeCompile FAILED"  is definitely gradle.   (Sorry, I just edited, but I thought it had that earlier.).  Though the path of using GraalVM seems to be the only one open to be at the moment.

Comment: Please share build.gradle.kts file

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved tracking down what pulled in the GraalVM plugin which turned out to be the `io.micronaut.application`, so it was simple to just use the `io.micronaut.minimum.application`.  Note that this excludes the graalvm plugin and also the docker plugin which you can include if you need it.

As a side note, I tried to make peace with GraalVM by installing a compatible  jdk version, but it failed with some unimplemented method error.   It's probably just immature on the mac.